# How to select data in rows using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

How can I use `LINQ` to `select` all the `Company Name` and `Company ID` from all the rows? I need something like this pseudo-code:

```
 var typedQry = from b in allData.AsEnumerable()
                where b.GetHeader("xxx") == "08/10/09 to 08/26/09"
                select CompanyName, CompanyID, ...
```

The code below selects only one Company Name. Instead, I want Company Name from all the rows:

```
var typedQry3  = from b in allData.AsEnumerable()
select new { compname0 = b._rows[0][5]};
```

The data in `_rows` are `Company Name` `(e.g., allData[0]._rows[0][5], allData[0]._rows[1][5],....)`, `Company ID`, and so forth.

However, `Company Name`, `Company ID`, and etc. are not defined in the DataProperty class. Their values are inserted into _rows from data files.

Any help is appreciated. Below is some code to help you understand my question.

```
List<DataProperty> allData = new List<DataProperty>();
```

The DataProperty class consists of

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _headers = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
private readonly List<string[]> _rows = new List<string[]>();
```

and these methods (among others):

```
public string[] GetDataRow(int rowNumber){return _rows[rowNumber];}
public void AddDataRow(string[] row){_rows.Add(row);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this to get all company names:

```
var AllCompanyNames = allData.SelectMany(u => u._rows.Select(t => t[5])).ToList();
```

and this, to get more property:

```
var Rows = allData.SelectMany(u => 
        u._rows.Select(t => new
        {
            CompanyName = t[5],
            Other1 = t[1],
            Other2 = t[2]
        }))
    .ToList();
```

and this, if you need to check any condition:

```
var FilteredRows = allData.SelectMany(u => 
        u._rows.Select(t => new
        {
            CompanyName = t[5],
            Other1 = t[1],
            Other2 = t[2]
        }))
    .Where(u => u.CompanyName == "XXX")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! The queries you provided are just what I need. Could you provide one more example that includes CompanyName and that shows how to sum two fields such as Credits and Debits and to order by CompanyName?

Comment: Your answer has been checked.

Answer (score 2):

according to your comment, if you need to the `sum` for each company you can try this:

```
var RowList1 = allData.SelectMany(u => u._rows.Select(t => new
        {
            CompanyName = t[5],
            Amount = Convert.ToInt64(t[1]) + Convert.ToInt64(t[2])
        }))
    .Where(u => u.CompanyName == "XXX")
    .OrderBy(u => u.CompanyName)
    .ToList();
```

and if you need to sum of the all companies, you can try this:

```
var SumAmount = allData.SelectMany(u => u._rows.Select(t => new
        {
             CompanyName = t[5],
             Amount = Convert.ToInt64(t[1]) + Convert.ToInt64(t[2])
        }))
    .Where(u => u.CompanyName == "XXX")
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Sum(u => u.Amount);
```

you can write your own and customized query using these

Comment: Thanks again!!! I checked your first answer as accepted. Since the system doesn't allow me to accept a second answer, I marked your second answer as useful, but in reality it's more than useful.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can receive rows and then iterate through them.
This example may help you

```
var rows = (from DataRow dRow in dTable.Rows
                            select new {col1=dRow["dataColumn1"],col2=dRow["dataColumn2"]});

        foreach (var row in distinctRows) 
        {
            var value1=row.col1.ToString();
            var value2=row.col2.ToString();  

        }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I need to convert allData (List allData = new List()) to Datable before I use the query above? The data come from data files, not from a database table.